# Programming custom PHP with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, themes

I have a question regarding PHP and Wordpress.

I recently started using Wordpress for a simple website but there is still one thing that I just don't understand. Lets say I made a cool website in php that also cointains my header, my footer and my menu. How do I implement the Wordpress CMS so that someone else can add an item in the menubar that I made, instead of adding an item in a theme made by someone else? I have a hard time finding such tutorials because most of them are for people with no programming interests and because of that they don't explain such things.

Comment: Look into [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Comment: Do you know if there are any visual (video's pref) tutorials aswell?

Comment: [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tag/wordpress/) usually put together good video tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is how to connect your menu to the wordpress admin, you can check this link: [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

that wordpress function will then generate a list of the menu items you add on the admin.

For example use this on your theme to display a menu from the admin with the name "Main Menu":

```
<div class="my-menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Menu' )); ?>
</div>
```